# sh.isBalancerRunning(): false

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am trying to `shard` a `mongodb database` like this:

1- Start each member of the `shard replica set`

```
mongod --shardsvr --port 27100 --replSet r1 --dbpath <some_path>\shardsvr\shardsvr1

mongod --shardsvr --port 27200 --replSet r2 --dbpath <some_path>\shardsvr\shardsvr2
```

2- Start each member of the `config server replica set`

```
mongod --configsvr --port 27020 --replSet cfg1 --dbpath <some_path>\configsvr\configsvr1
```

3- Connect to `config server replica set`

```
mongo --port 27020
```

4- Initiate the replica set

```
conf = {
    _id: "cfg1",
    members: [ 
        {
            _id:0, 
            host: "localhost:27020"
        }
    ]
}

rs.initiate(conf)
```

5- Start the `mongos` and specify the `--configdb` parameter

```
mongos --configdb cfg1/localhost:27020 --port 28000
```

6- Initiate the `replica set` of each `shard`

```
mongo --port 27100
var config = {_id: "r1", members: [{_id:0, host:"localhost:27100"}]}    
rs.initiate(config)
exit    
mongo --port 27200
var config = {_id: "r2", members: [{_id:0, host:"localhost:27200"}]}
rs.initiate(config)
exit
```

7- Connect to `mongos` to add `shards`

```
mongo --port 28000

sh.addShard("r1/localhost:27100")
sh.addShard("r2/localhost:27200")
```

8- Add some data

```
use sharddb

for (i = 10000; i < 30000; i++){
    db.example.insert({
        author: "author" + i,
        post_title: "Blog Post by Author " + i,
        date: new Date()
    });
}

db.example.count()
```

9- Enable `sharding`

```
sh.enableSharding("sharddb")
```

10- Create the `index` as part of `sh.shardCollection()`

```
db.example.ensureIndex({author : 1}, true)
sh.shardCollection("sharddb.example", {author: 1})
```

11- Check if `balancer` is running

```
sh.isBalancerRunning()
```

However, in this step, I get a `false` as response, and I dont know what I did wrong to get this. I followed the steps of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3V8SzV-f0s) tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only 20000 documents that are ~100 bytes each, there is probably only 1 chunk.

Check with

```
use sharddb
db.printShardingStatus()
```

I repeated the steps you listed above, and got the following result:

```
{  "_id" : "sharddb",  "primary" : "shard02",  "partitioned" : true }
    sharddb.example
        shard key: { "author" : 1 }
        unique: false
        balancing: true
        chunks:
            shard02 1
        { "author" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "author" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard02 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

The mongos will monitor what it has added to each chunk, and notify the config server to consider splitting when it has seen enough data added.  Then the balancer will automatically be activated when one shard contains several more chunks than another.

If you insert enough documents to trigger automatic splitting, or manually split the chunk, the balancer will begin doing its thing.

Comment: use the `sh.split`, `sh.splitFind` or `sh.splitAt` commands.  See [Split Chunks in a Sharded Cluter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)